# Check data-id based on id of an anchor item in a loop checkin if the element is within an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, custom-data-attribute

Here's my problem.

I want to show a bunch of element if my user will click a link. Each link has an id and each bunch of elements is wrapped in a main div.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="col-md-55">
    <div>
        <img src="/wp-content/themes/wpboot/images/svg/aaps_cannabis_icon.svg">
        <h4>something</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <a href="#" id="course1">All Courses</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-55">
    <div>
        <img src="/wp-content/themes/wpboot/images/svg/aaps_nutrition_icon.svg">
        <h4>something 2</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <a href="#" id="course2">All Courses</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3" data-id="course1">
    <div class="col-4">
        <div>
            <h3>Course1</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3" data-id="course2">
    <div class="col-4">
        <div>
            <h3>Course2</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I will access all of my element with jquery:

```
var buttonhideprogram = $('a');
var targetprograms = $('.col-md-9');
var targetprogramsid =[];
targetprograms.each(function() {
    targetprogramsid.push( $(this).data("id"));
});

buttonhideprogram.click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$(this).hasClass('Open')) {
        $(this).addClass('Open');
        var things = $(this).attr('id');
        if ($.inArray(things, targetprogramsid)!='-1') {
            console.log(targetprogramsid);
            targetprogramsid.show();
        }
    }
});
```

Easy enough, I will declare first all of the element to access with jquery, then  I will create an array with all the programs, then again on click I will do other stuff but most importantly I will create a variable called things which is the element that I will click and I will find if the id is present in my array.

And from then, I still not be able to complete the code, because the code works so far, but I don't know how to hide the element that matches the id attribute in the array (and than hide).

any suggestion?

Comment: If you're just trying to open and close thing, why not just `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`, or `.toggleClass()`. `-1` is not `'-1'`.

Comment: that's for another purpose.. the important thing is the array to match id with data-id

Comment: I do not think that the code, as it is, is really working. targetprogramsid.show(); is an array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is incorrect and cannot work. You are doing hide on an array.
No need to assign Open to link, or even of the courses. Just check if it is already visible or not.
Here is all what you need:

```
var buttonhideprogram = $('a');

buttonhideprogram.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var things = $(this).attr('id');
  //console.log(things)
  var elem = $('.col-md-9[data-id=' + things + ']');

  if (elem.is(":visible")) {
    elem.hide();
  } else {
    elem.show();
  }
});
```

[Here is a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/0dz2pcs5/)

Comment: I did in this way:

var target = $('.col-md-9[data-id="'+things+'"]');
            targetprograms.removeClass('col-md-offset-3');
            target.show();

IS there a more elegant way to write the code using my variable target and just adding [data-id=' + things + ']?

Answer (score -1):

Why not just locate the element with the correct data-id.

```js
var things = $(this).attr('id');
var target = $("[data-id='" + things + "']");
target.show();
```

Comment: You must be having a bad day. Combining jQuery with raw JS an expecting it to work is funny.

Comment: The idea is good but it throws me an error:

target.show is not a function

Comment: @StackSlave Yeah, oops.